# Entity Send to Server Problem

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity, domainservices

On the client-side I add all **related entities** (navigation properties) to my main **entity** and attach it to the list and call **SubmitChange**. But on the server-side, all related entities are missing!

Code:

**Client:**

```
DomainService1 domainService1= new DomainService1();
.
.
.
WorkCode newWorkCode = new WorkCode();
newWorkCode.Date = DateTime.Now;

.
.
.

for(Work item in WorkList)
{
 newWorkCode.Works.Add(item) 
}

.
.
.

domainService1.WorkCodes.Attach(newWorkCode);
domainService1.InsertWorkCode(newWorkCode);     
      dsMaintenance.SubmitChanges(submitOperation =>
      {
        if (!submitOperation.HasError)
        {

        }
      },
            null);
```

**Server:**

```
[Update(UsingCustomMethod = true)]
public void InsertWorkCode(WorkCode workCode)
{
    //////// workCode.Works = 0 ///////////////////

  this.ObjectContext.WorkCodes.AddObject(workCode);            
}
```

Comment: Does this need a RIA services tag? It seems like it does. Are you using Entity Framework? Code First?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing here. But if I want to add stuff I do it like this and it works:

```
Context = new DomainContext();

var customer = new Customer() { /* ... */ };
var order = new Order() { Customer = customer, /* ... */ };

Context.Customers.Add(customer);
Context.Orders.Add(order);
```

If you like the other approach though, you can do that too like this:

```
var customer = new Customer() { /* ... */ };
var order = new Order { /* ... */ };

customer.Orders.Add(order);
Context.Customers.Add(customer);
```

Now you just submit:

```
var submitOperation = Context.SubmitChanges();
submitOperation.Completed += // [...]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems good but at the line Context.Customers.Add(customer); I will get the error: EntititySet of Type Customer does not support the Add operation.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that you are working with a DomainContext?

Comment: I have defined a DomainService on the server and created a new DomainService object on the client side and used it.

Comment: You have to use the Context it generates for you. (the name should be something like DomainService1Context)

Comment: How can I get the DomainServiceContext? Any sample? or Tutorial?

Comment: It depends on the folder you put it in in your server project. E.g. if you have a project SilverlightProject, then your server-projfect is SilverlightProject.Web. Now, if you have your domain service in a folder named "Services", on the client the domainCONTEXT lives in SilverlightProject.Web.Services. Hope this helps. If you like the book "Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4" is good. It's a very good read and teaches you all the concepts.